# Is it possible to do DDL statement in a dynamic pl/sql block

Tags: oracle

I know that I can't make a DDL in a pl/sql block.
I wanted to know if I could do that with dynamic sql.

I have tried to drop an object. I don't get a message error like not possible.
But I can continue to use the same object after that.

```
CREATE TYPE arguments_r IS  OBJECT
(
    q    integer,
    b            INTEGER
);
/

declare
    a arguments_r;
begin
   execute immediate 'drop type arguments_r';
   a:=arguments_r(1,1);
end;
/
```

I wonder if have made an error that cause that my dynamic statement is not executed.

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/04m3P-dZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DDL is executed - you can see that [if you try to use it again](https://dbfiddle.uk/YplKRnHm).

After your original block is compiled it doesn't matter that the type is dropped within it during execution, because (I believe) you're are only dealing with data held in memory - and the block already has all the information it needs to create the instance of that type. Dropping the type doesn't seem to affect you. That doesn't mean it's a good idea though.

You'd see a different result with other types of object:

```
create table t (id number);

begin
   execute immediate 'drop table t';
   insert into t (id) values (42);
end;
/

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

That's a run-time error, not a compilation error. The table object still has to exist to be able to insert into it, because it isn't memory-only. (If the table doesn't exist when the block is parsed then you get a compilation error - ORA-06550 as well as ORA-00942.)

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wZ9FV6of)